# How to configure the project and virtualenv paths in crontab to schedule jobs in Django?

Tags: python, django, cron

I am using a library called django_cron to schedule tasks with Django. I've already done all the required setup, including, but not limited to adding this chunk of code to the crons.py file:

```
class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 1 # every 2 minutes.

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'core.my_cron_job'    # a unique code

    def do(self):
       pass;
```

However, I am having a lot of trouble to configure the contrab command in the contrab editor. I am currently using this command (because I am using a virtual environment):

```
* * * * * source /Users/myame/Desktop/dev/Websites/django_env/bin/activate
&& python /Users/myname/Desktop/dev/Websites/project/manage.py runcrons
```

I am getting this error:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.kdldvixya8":4: bad minute
crontab: errors in crontab file, can't install
```

How can I solve this? What's wrong with it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820102/cron-bad-minute-error-home-cron0-bad-minute-crontab-errors-in-crontab-file

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to activate the virtualenv, you can just call python within there directly.  Try like this

```
0 * * * * /Users/myame/Desktop/dev/Websites/django_env/bin/python /Users/myname/Desktop/dev/Websites/project/manage.py runcrons
```

Should run on the hour

Comment: I still get these errors: crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.zj9EsO3YYN":1: bad minute
crontab: errors in crontab file, can't install

Comment: I managed to add the cron job to the crontab -e, but the task is still not run :(

Comment: goto root directory on your server and type `/Users/myame/Desktop/dev/Websites/django_env/bin/python /Users/myname/Desktop/dev/Websites/project/manage.py runcrons`.  Does it run or what error do you get

Comment: (I am actually running locally) When I run the command you told me to, the task is run, but it does not run automatically (as is the job of cron tasks)